# How to convert the Date into words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

Can anyone help me regarding the conversion of Date into words - e.g: '12/04/2011' convert to 'one twelve zero four two zero one one' ...?

Can we do this using javascript?

Do we have any plugin in jquery?

Comment: What does the `one` at the beginning stand for??

Comment: Just a question, in your example - for 2011 the numbers are broken down into single numbers, where for 12, they are kept as double digit. Is this intentional? Do you want days and months as double digits and the year as singles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array:

```
var numbers = ['zero','one','two'...]
```

Then loop through the string containing the date (dateVar) using the array as a reference for the names.

```
for (i=1;i<dateVar.length;i++){
 document.write( numbers[parseInt(dateVar.charAt(i))]+' ');
}
```

Happy to help work out the specifics if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link

http://xl.barasch.com/cCo11432.htm

and you will able to find the answer